# Implementing Continuous Scrolling UI Pattern in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have implemented Continuous Page Scrolling according to this post given below

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/b8381915-06d9-4538-b4bb-5ac2a8e73f34/implementing-continuous-s.aspx

But problem is

-How to handle post back events on scrolling e-g  On Scrolling i render a user control in ashx handler where I have a asp.net button with click event but don't know how to handle click event because on clicking it does not fire click event except submiting a form and redirect to ashx handler with white screen.
Has any one implemented this?

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm not answering your question directly, but you might want to try [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) instead.  Its a lot easier to implement since all of the scrolling handling code is wrapped up neatly into a re-usable jQuery plugin.